# MySQL order by (str to int)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT `01` FROM perf WHERE year = '2013' order by CAST(`01` AS INT) LIMIT 3
```

Column 01 has numeric values as varchar. I need to order top 3 of '01' as integer. Why doesn't this query working?

Table like this;

```
+----------------------+
| name | 01 | 02 | year|
+----------------------+
|name1 | 90 |*** |2013 |
+----------------------+
|name2 | 93 | 55 |2013 |
+----------------------+
|name3 |*** | 78 |2013 |
+----------------------+
```

Query should order by 01 (dismiss ***) and give names and values.

Comment: can you give sample records and desired result?

Comment: this will give the lowest three values of your column.  Do you want `ORDER BY ... DESC` ?

Comment: Order by ... desc, yes. This query is giving SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

MySQL doesn't permit you  to `CAST('01' AS INT)`. It expects instead a `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`.

```
SELECT `01` FROM perf WHERE year = '2013' order by CAST(`01` AS SIGNED) LIMIT 3
```

Review the [MySQL docs on `CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for full details.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('01' AS SIGNED);
+----------------------+
| CAST('01' AS SIGNED) |
+----------------------+
|                    1 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To force the non-numeric strings to be sorted last, you will need to apply a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` which assigns them an absurdly high value.  The condition should test that the value in `01` is not equal to `0`, *and* when cast to a `SIGNED` the result is not `0`, owing to the fact that non-numeric strings will cast to zero.

If those conditions are not met, the string is assumed to be non-numeric, and given a value of 999999999 in the `ORDER BY`, which pushes them to the end.  They're subsequently ordered by `name`.

```
SELECT * FROM perf 
WHERE year = '2013'
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN (`01` <> '0' AND CAST(`01` AS SIGNED) <> 0) THEN CAST(`01` AS SIGNED) ELSE 999999999 END,
  name
LIMIT 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/846e2/6

To make these sort descending, use an absurdly low value (negative) instead of a high value

```
  CASE WHEN (`01` <> '0' AND CAST(`01` AS SIGNED) <> 0) THEN CAST(`01` AS SIGNED) ELSE -999999999 END DESC,
```