# OrderBy in varchar containing integer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have a column of type "varchar" but it consists of integer.

When I make a query with orderBy, it results like below.

```
10
11
12
9
```

I have implemented orderBy like below:

```
->orderBy("stdmap.prvid");
```

When I run query directly in phpmyadmin  with order stdmap.prvid+0, it is giving me correct result. But I am not sure how to add +0 in laravel query.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: @Zhorov using mysql

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709058/mysql-order-by-str-to-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw("stdmap.prvid+0"));
```

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

How about with `orderByRaw`?

```
->orderByRaw('stdmap.prvid+0 asc')
```

Answer (score 0):

Order the resulting collection

```
$unorderedThings = Thing::orderBy('id')->get();
$orderedThings = $unorderedThings->sort();
```

Hope this helps